# Visual Studio Code from Administrator PowerShell

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I open a Windows PowerShell with administrative rights, I can "notepad {file}" and edit and save. For example I often edit my \drivers\etc\hosts file working on test vs live domains.

If I do "code {file}" it says I can't save file.

Why does notepad know and run as an administrator, code does not? From PowerShell I'm running code as an admin, just like if I use notepad instead...

C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc> notepad hosts

Edit hosts file, save. No problem

C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc> code hosts

Cannot save file, permission denied

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue following the steps you have provided. Please provide more information about how to reproduce it. Are you sure you have actually opened powershell with admin rights?

Comment: Yes. I double checked with both an Admin powershell and a non-admin one both open.

Comment: I hate having to allow it - via another popup - every time. I guess I assumed since Notepad knew the difference, Code would too, but maybe just because Notepad is a built-in. 

Are you saying if you try `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc> code hosts` in Admin PowerShell that it does allow you to save the file without prompting for Admin rights?

Comment: yep⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀